# Sending and receiving an image over sockets/Internet with C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, ip, client-server

Problem:
In TCP/IP one sender and one Receiver.
4 The computer is connected to the Internet via  Two Router.

Computer A and Computer B connected to Internet Via Router 1

Computer C and Computer D Connected to Internet via Router 2

How can Computer A Send Continuous Images to Computer C.

How Can Computer C Receive Via Port or anything else?

My Problem is if I am sending images via internet I have must be required IP Address of Receiver mean Computer C. But in this Case, all computer Connected Via Router. I can’t find Computer IP Address because it is connected to Router. The router has one public IP Address. Ex.   Router 2 has two Computer connected then how can I identify “Computer C” IP Address and Computer D IP Address

How can we communicate this two pc which is connected via two different routers?

Mean one pc can send data and pc receive data continuously. Both and connected via the Internet.

I have read many posts on this website but I can’t find how to find IP Address of computer when the computer is connected to Router and Communicate via the internet.

Comment: That's what ports are for. You need to setup your router to do what you want. There's no programming aspect to your question

Comment: Thanks For Reply. Port means Computer Port for receiving data. But one question is in my mind i can configure my router but receiver router is not available at my place so can i configure via C# programming or i must have configure manually?

Comment: Yes. That's what you need to configure

Comment: I want to sending continuous Images by Computer A which is connected to Router1 and Computer B is receive continuous images but computer B is connected to another router ex.Router 2. How can communicate Computer A and Computer B where both computers connected  different router?